# Is there a way to change (delete) a standard phrase going after a single post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-theming

my question is about Wordpress.

Is there a way to get access to the phrase, going after a single post?

"**Enjoy this article**

If you have enjoyed this article consider subscribing to our RSS Feed"

Thanks a lot)

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress, content in your site that is *not controlled* in the Posts, Pages, Widgets or Links in the Administration area almost always will be found in the `.php` files in your theme.

So to find the test "**Enjoy this article**" you'll need to get familiar with [editing theme files](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files). It's likely that this text is in a file called `index.php` and/or `single.php`, though may be in other places also.

If your website resides in a folder called `public_html`, and wordpress is installed in a directory called `blog`, then your theme files will be at this path: `public_html/blog/wp-content/themes/{theme_name}/`. You will need to edit the `index.php` and/or `single.php` files at this path, where `{theme_name}` is the directory of your active theme.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

For more information on WP theming, editing, and what the different files are for, see this very useful tutorial.

http://www.wpdesigner.com/2007/02/19/so-you-want-to-create-wordpress-themes-huh/